# How to get all media with conversion in Spatie?

Tags: laravel, media-library, laravel-medialibrary

I am working with Spatie Media library in Laravel ,

I can only get first media url while mentioning conversion type & collection :

```
$model->getFirstMediaUrl('collection','conversion');
```

How can I get all of the media with collection and conversion that I want ?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

```
@foreach($model->getMedia('gallery') as $image)
 <img src="{{asset($image->getUrl('my-gallery-conversion'))}}">
@endforeach
```

If there are no conversions leave the getUrl empty